# CSS hover sliding animation top to bottom not working

Tags: html, css

I working with sociable on hover background-color slide down from top to bottom I wrote CSS but I don't know why it's not working.

```css
ul.socials {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.socials li {
  padding: 12px;
}

.socials li.facebook {
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eaeaea 50%, #3B5998 50%);
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: background-position 0.5s;
  transition: background-position 0.5s;
}

.socials li.facebok:hover {
  background-position: 0 -100%;
  color: #ffffff;
}

i.fa.fa-facebook {
  color: #3B5998;
}

i.fa.fa-twitter {
  color: #00A0D1;
}

i.fa.fa-dribbble {
  color: #ea4c88;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a2e210f715.js"></script>
<div class="social-wrap">
  <ul class="socials">
    <li class="facebook"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li class="twitter"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li class="dribbble"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code for your reference. I made sliding effect working for all 3 icons.

```css
ul.socials {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.socials li {
  padding: 12px;
}

.socials li.facebook {
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eaeaea 50%, #3B5998 50%);
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: background-position 0.5s;
  transition: background-position 0.5s;
}
.socials li.twitter {
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eaeaea 50%, #00A0D1 50%);
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: background-position 0.5s;
  transition: background-position 0.5s;
}
.socials li.dribbble {
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eaeaea 50%, #ea4c88 50%);
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: background-position 0.5s;
  transition: background-position 0.5s;
}
.socials li:hover {
  background-position: 0 -100%;
  color: #ffffff;
}

i.fa.fa-facebook {
  color: #3B5998;
}

i.fa.fa-twitter {
  color: #00A0D1;
}

i.fa.fa-dribbble {
  color: #ea4c88;
}
.socials li:hover a i {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a2e210f715.js"></script>
<div class="social-wrap">
  <ul class="socials">
    <li class="facebook"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li class="twitter"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li class="dribbble"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A typo mistake : use `.socials li.facebook:hover` instead of `.socials li.facebok:hover`

```css
ul.socials {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.socials li {
  padding: 12px;
}

.socials li.facebook {
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eaeaea 50%, #3B5998 50%);
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: background-position 0.5s;
  transition: background-position 0.5s;
}

.socials li.facebook:hover {
  background-position: 0 -100%;
  color: #ffffff;
}

i.fa.fa-facebook {
  color: #3B5998;
}

i.fa.fa-twitter {
  color: #00A0D1;
}

i.fa.fa-dribbble {
  color: #ea4c88;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a2e210f715.js"></script>
<div class="social-wrap">
  <ul class="socials">
    <li class="facebook"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li class="twitter"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li class="dribbble"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```